# React Native Stack Navigator Use State

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I try to make Share State Data From MyStack Component.
Components of Second Data is Always changed But First Screen is not
Could you tell me about what is problem of this??
And What do i have to Change.
thank you :D

```
import React ,{ useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function First({route , navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title={route.params.count.toString()}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Second')}/>
    </View>
  );
} 

function Second({route , navigation }) {
  route.params.setCount(route.params.count + 1);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title={route.params.count.toString()}
        onPress={() => { navigation.goBack()}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="First" component={First} initialParams={{ count: count , setCount  : setCount }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={Second} initialParams={{ count: count ,setCount  : setCount}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack props={props}/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you also elaborate what is it supposed to do if there is not error and also the screenshot of the error being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the above not working is the FirstScreen is not being re rendered. You cant dynamically change the intialparams after the screen is rendered.
Even your screen 2 is not working properly, you set it but you see the updated value when you revisit the screen.

The way to fix this is to use the context api which you can use to skip the navigation params.

And always use a hook like useEffect or a buttonclick to update the context otherwise it would keep rerendering which would result in an error.
The code would be like below.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const appContext = createContext();

function First({ route, navigation }) {
  const context = useContext(appContext);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title={context.count.toString()}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Second')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Second({ route, navigation }) {
  const context = useContext(appContext);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title={context.count.toString()}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Add to Count"
        onPress={() => {
          context.setCount(context.count + 1);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const state = { count, setCount };

  return (
    <appContext.Provider value={state}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="First" component={First} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={Second} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </appContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack props={props} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you For Help! 
This is what i really want to know! :D  
i will consider of rendering system

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: The context approach is very useful. You can also see extra info in this link [https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)